# How to create 32-bit png with alpha in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png

I need icon image 32-bit png with alpha for play store. But i have no idea about alpha images. how to create 32 bit png with alpha using photoshop. If you have any video tutorial please send me link.

Comment: Another one How to create whatsapp supported gif file in photoshop. I have created gif file using photoshop but not supported in whatsapp.

Comment: You just delete the background layer and paint on a transparent layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the fast commentators have spitted the core of this out at least half a day ago. I write slower.

32 bit PNG with alpha is just the ordinary colored PNG from Photoshop. You must set your image to have Image Mode = RGB color, 8 bit/channel.

Do not have a background. Merge all your painting, photo and effect layers into one that's NOT the backgroud, but a layer in the Layers panel

The alpha is the transparency channel. That exists, if there's no spesific background layer. The alpha makes PNGs attractive just because the transparency is possible. JPGs do not have it.

When you save as PNG, Photoshop asks "Interlace or not". "Yes" makes possible the image appear partially somehow faster in slow systems. Consult the customer, is it needed or not. I have never needed it.

Comment: @RamaKrishnan if this was useful, accept it. Otherwise the system keeps this unsolved and do not show it if somebody tries to find solutioms.

Comment: @RamaKrishnan actually no need to accept, this is seemingly solved long time ago  perfectly and the system knows it